# Order by dates in current month first, then by all other dates

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have date in database column, records as follows

```
Startdate 
Dec-1-2011
Dec-1-2012
April-5-2013
Dec-12-2013
Jan-1-2013
Jan-12-2013
Feb-25-2013
March-2-2013
March-3-2013
April-6-2013
Feb-1-2013
Dec-1-2013
Dec-1-2010
```

I want all the records in sql query but order by current month and year, so the current month and year record will come first and then others.

StartDAte column data type is date

I tried this

Case When month(StartDate) < month(GetDate()) Then month(StartDate) +12
ELSE month(StartDate) END
it gives me current month date + any year dates first.
but I want current month + current year date first and the others.

Comment: What type is this column, `datetime` or `varchar`? What have you tried? What means: _"current month and year record will come first and then others"_? What is the second, what the last?

Comment: What queries did you try? What hasn't worked? What are you having problems with? What data type is `Startdate`?

Comment: Actually I want current month date's data first then other month's date, startdate data type is date

Comment: I tried   
 Case When month(StartDate) < month(GetDate()) Then month(StartDate) +12
ELSE month(StartDate) END it is giving me first current month date but it includes the current month + previous year date first. I want current month and current year date first and then others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the `startdate` column is of data type `date` or `datetime`, and there are dates after the current date and you want those dates that has current year and month come first, then you can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY CASE 
           WHEN MONTH(startDate) = MONTH(GETDATE())
            AND YEAR(StartDate)  = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 0
           ELSE 1
         END, startDate;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f604/4)

Comment: You might want to swap the values, now you get the dates of the current month last, as 0 comes before 1.

Comment: @Guffa - Sorry, ypercube has fixed it. Thanks.